# How to make a mongodB embedded request in SpringBoot with MongoRepository?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I have two collections :

- "sessions" with fields "teacherId" and "subjectId"
- "subjects"with fields "id", "name" and "nbhours".

I look forward to make a function `getSubjectsByTeacherId(id_passed_as_parametre)`  which is  a function that retrieves all the subjects figuring in it's sessions by teacherId.
In other words,  if it was a  sql request it  would be  something like  that :

```
SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM seances WHERE teacherId = 'id_passed_as_parametre' )
```

Comment: are u using spring-data-mongodb? Also show your entity and repository class

Comment: @pvpkiran no am not using this spring-data-mongodb

Comment: what do u meant by mongorepository

Comment: @pvpkiran I think it's a library It is used to invoke database query by annotating the query method